# How do I develop a spatial regression model when the Y and X points are partially misaligned? Do I have to use a grid?

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, spatial

What concept would I use to develop a spatial regression model for misaligned Insurance Claims and Policy data? For example, consider a situation where I have 1000 points that represent policies, and 100 points that represent claims. While some of the claims are located at the same spatial location as some of the policies, most are not. In addition, I have 20 predictor variables associated with the policy points, and 2 predictor variables associated with the claim points.

**How can I develop a spatial regression where Y represents Claim $ amount, and X represents all of the predictor variables associated with the policies?**

The image below is a toy example of this situation, where blue points represent policies and red triangles represent claims. Triangles either align perfectly with the circles, or they do not align with any circles. I'm assuming I have complete information about the policies (circles), so there are no missing circles.

[image: Blue circles = Policies, Red triangles = Claims]

Comment: Questions about programs/coding are off-topic here, so I'd recommend that you edit this to focus on your statistical question.

Comment: Oh sorry! I'll try and fix it.

Comment: what do you want to predict?

Comment: I want to predict Claim amount ($) at the claim points

Comment: Should the triangles align perfectly with one of the existing circles? Or is there the possibility of them belonging to missing circles?

Comment: And is there spatial structure in the policy data? In other words, do you need to consider some sort of interpolation, or identify the single location (circle) a claim (triangle) is associated with?

Comment: Triangles either align perfectly with the circles, or they do not align with any circles. I'm assuming I have complete information about the policies (circles), so there are no missing circles.

Comment: There is a spatial structure in the data, so I think I do need to consider some sort of interpolation. I guess I was wondering if I just need to do some kind of spatial regression kriging over a grid, or if any statistician knew of a more advanced statistical solution? I looked into spMisalignGLM in R, but I think it deals with a different scenario. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/spBayes/versions/0.4-2/topics/spMisalignGLM

Comment: @Kristaps (the @ is how you tag specific people to respond to in comments) if there are missing circles, then I think kriging is probably your best bet.

Comment: @mkt Gotcha - thank you mkt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Turning my comments into an answer)

This problem is probably best solved by a spatial interpolation approach such as [kriging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriging). An alternative approach would be to select the nearest by some distance metric and treat that as the true location. In the first approach, some avoidable error is introduced by using information from more distant points if the nearest point is the correct one. In the second approach, results will be perfect if the nearest point is the correct one. But for the subset of points for which this is not true, this approach will produce results that are worse, possibly by a substantial amount.